# pandas: get unique rows based on their unordered multiple columns values

Tags: python, pandas

Having DataFrame

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[2,1]], columns=['id_1', 'id_2'])
Out [1]:
   id_1  id_2
0     1     2
1     2     3
2     3     4
3     2     1
```

how and what is the best way to select rows with `id_1=i`, `id_2=j`, such that there are no row with `id_1=j` and  `id_2=i` in `df`?

For above example the expected result is

```
   id_1  id_2
1     2     3
2     3     4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can firstly sort the values by row, then check duplicates:

```
df[~df.apply(pd.np.sort, axis=1).duplicated(keep=False)]

#   id_1    id_2
#1     2       3
#2     3       4
```

Comment: Thanks, `pd.np.sort` seems very useful.